# Toggle MongoDB document between multiple preset fields using Javascript events in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create a Meteor event to update the "class" field of a document when its portion of the template is clicked on. I need to rotate between 3 separate preset values for the field. So far I have tried using jQuery if else statements along with .hasClass() to determine which class was currently assigned but to no avail.

```
Template.buttonGrey.events({
 "click .toggleGrey": function (e) {
   if($(this).hasClass("myButtonGrey")) {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkFast"}});
   } else if ($(this).hasClass("myButtonGreyBlinkFast")) {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkSlow"}});
   } else {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGrey"}});
   }
 },
});
```

Heres a copy of my HTML Meteor template as well.

```
<template name="buttonGrey">
<a href="#" class="toggleGrey {{class}}">{{number}}</a>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting the element which triggered the event (and *not* the document itself), you should use `$(e.target)` instead of `$(this)`:

```
Template.buttonGrey.events({
 "click .toggleGrey": function (e) {
   if($(e.target).hasClass("myButtonGrey")) {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkFast"}});
   } else if ($(e.target).hasClass("myButtonGreyBlinkFast")) {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkSlow"}});
   } else {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGrey"}});
   }
 },
});
```

But given the data context, you can just as well use directly `this` (being the document, in this case) without jQuery:

```
Template.buttonGrey.events({
 "click .toggleGrey": function (e) {
   if(this.class === "myButtonGrey") {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkFast"}});
   } else if (this.class === "myButtonGreyBlinkFast") {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGreyBlinkSlow"}});
   } else {
    ButtonsGrey.update(this._id, {$set: {class: "myButtonGrey"}});
   }
 },
});
```